# Open a react app in Heroku (webpack output is served from)

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have created a basic React APP (via create-react-app) that I deployed successfully to Heroku.

Although the deployment was valid, I can’t open the app. In the past, I did perform the same process of deploying a React APP form my Git account and it was working perfectly.

I can’t understand from the logs what is the issue and have no idea what as change?

```
020-04-17T18:19:35.823931+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-04-17T18:19:35.823933+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-17T18:19:37.539377+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at 
http://172.18.111.10/
2020-04-17T18:19:37.539661+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-04-17T18:19:37.539739+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is 
served from /app/public
2020-04-17T18:19:37.539811+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-04-17T18:19:37.539981+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-04-17T18:19:37.539982+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-17T18:19:37.638556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed


{
 "name": "my-app",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": false,
 "engines": {
  "node": "12.13.0",
  "npm": "6.14.2",
  "yarn": "1.19.0"
}, 
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
 },
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

I am very puzzled and want to understand why it’s not working.

Looking for some tails for this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm troubleshooting the same issue.

Comment: I did but was long time ago and I am not working on this project any more. Sorry that I cant help you.